# getting exception in updating data base sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

to update a row in data base  when i press a button

```
public void updateContact(long id, String x, String y,String angle)
        {
        ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
        editCon.put(KEY_X, x);
        editCon.put(KEY_Y, y);
        editCon.put(KEY_ANGLE, angle);

        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, KEY_ROWID + id, null);

        }
```

and i use it `entry.updateContact(1, Double.toString(db1), Double.toString(db2), Double.toString(db3));`

but i get the exception: `no such colum: _id1 (code1): , while compiling: UPDATE SavedTable SET position_y=?, position_x=?, position_angle=? WHERE_id1`

even though i have a database with one row ( i create the entry in my oncreate method of main activity)

Comment: post your full code ,with log

Comment: Have you updated the database version number since changing any column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KEY_ROWID + id` will not work as you expect! `KEY_ROWID` is probably a String containing `_id` and your `id` variable contains `1` which will result in `_id1`.

You need this:

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null);
```

or better:

```
ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

EDIT:

```
// pseudocode
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null....);
if (c != null) {
    if (c.getCount() >= 1) {
        // there is an entry - just update
    } else { 
        // no entry - create entry
    }
} else {
    // error? But definitively no entry so create one
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The thing is I am updating the first row all the time. and each time my app runs I will call createEntry (which i put in onCreate of main activity) which adds one line. Actually I put that createEntry with fake numbers to just have something to update with needed data (when user presses the button). How can I limit all these to only one line of database?

Comment: If you just want to have one line in that table, create a `createOrUpdate()` method. There you need to query the table to see if there is an entry already there. In that case you use an update on that line (the ID should always be 1 in this case). If there is no line in that table, you create one. Simple case handling :)

Comment: "There you need to query the table to see if there is an entry already there" Could you plz tell how to do this?

Comment: I added some pseudocode of the basic `createOrUpdate()` method. I think googling `create or update database` should give some good results, too.

Comment: I tried to implement it but have problem I posted it in new thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745531/updating-or-inserting-in-a-table-with-keeping-the-row-numbers-to-one) could you plz have a look

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your `update()` method:

```
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, KEY_ROWID + " = ?", 
          new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
```

Problem was that you specified incorrect `WHERE` clause. You wrote this:

```
KEY_ROWID + id
```

this is translated on the database layer as **`_id1`** where it was interpreted as column.

You needed **`_id = 1`** and this is achieved by `KEY_ROWID + " = ?"` where placeholder will be replaced with value from string array.