# updating or inserting in a table with keeping the row numbers to one

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to see if there is something in my table update it and if not insert one row. So basically I will have one row always in my table.

```
   public void createOrupdate(long id,String x, String y, String angle){
            String[] columns= new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_X, KEY_Y, KEY_ANGLE};
            Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();

            if (c!=null){
                editCon.put(KEY_X, x);
                editCon.put(KEY_Y, y);
                editCon.put(KEY_ANGLE, angle);
                ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editCon, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
            }
            else{
                editCon.put(KEY_X, x);
                editCon.put(KEY_Y, y);
                editCon.put(KEY_ANGLE, angle);
                ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, editCon);
            }

        }

        public String getData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] columns= new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_X, KEY_Y, KEY_ANGLE};
            Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            String result= "";
            int iRow= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iX= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_X);
            int iY= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_Y);
            int iAngle= c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ANGLE);
            int i= 0;

            for( c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
                result= result+ c.getString(iRow)+ " "+ c.getString(iX)+ " " +c.getString(iY)+ " "+ c.getString(iAngle)+"\n";

            }
            return result;
        }
```

But when I use `entry.createOrupdate(1, Double.toString(db1), Double.toString(db2), Double.toString(db3));` in my code there is nothing in my table and no exception and nothing. when i use update or insert separately it works.. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check for `c!=null` is not enough. The cursor can be not null even when the result of the query was empty. That means you need to get the amount of rows by using `c.getCount()` and check if that returns `0` or `1`.

PS: This `for( c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){` is a pretty ugly use for a loop. You should change that to something like `while(c.moveToNext())`.

`moveToNext()` will be the same like `moveToFirst()` on a fresh created cursor object.

Comment: Thanks again! apparently i have no idea about data bases. is there any good fast tutorial about it? SQL and SQLite use same syntax? I mean if I can handle SQLite can I handle SQL also? could you give me some general guidelines?

Comment: Both are basically the same but they have some few differences. Some basics can be learned here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp and after that the best experience is by doing something. Do some small projects, dig into open source projects to learn, do mistakes and figure out the solution or ask for help and learn from the given solutions. Get your hands dirty is probably the best tip I can give :)